# Objeto de objetos en TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Tengo definido la siguiente clase:

```
class Factura {
  id: number;
  entidad: {
    nombre: string;
    direccion: string;
  };
  factura: string;
}
```

y he definido el objeto,

`let f = new Factura();`

realizo la asignación de la primera propiedad sin problemas:

`f.id = 1;`

Sin embargo al realizar la asignación:

`f.entidad.nombre = 'Nombre de la empresa';`

no se obtiene el resultado esperado pues no realiza la asignación correctamente. Cuál pudiera ser la causa? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes inicializar tu objeto entidad antes de asignarle un valor a alguno de sus campos:

```
f.entidad = {nombre: 'Nombre de entidad'};
```

Si definieses la clase Entidad podrías hacer:

```
class Entidad {
    nombre: string;
    direccion: string;
}
```

Ahora tu clase Factura declararía la propiedad `entidad` como un objeto de la clase Entidad y podrías hacer `f.entidad = new Entidad();`